# Plugin task executes after configuration phase

Tags: gradle

I am building a whole suite of plugins for a new build pipeline.  I have certain metadata that if it is not present in the build file, i want it to fail.  for example

```
inventory_link: '124djsj39r'
```

This links the build back to our inventory system.  If that tag is not present in the build, I don't want the developer to be able to do squat.  no tests, no compiles, no builds, no nothing.  I want the project to be a worthless group of files.

Now reading the docs, i understand the build lifecycle, sorta.  There's an init, config, execute, clean. basically  How do I configure a custom plugin (writing it as an independant jar) so that a validation task executes automatically that checks to make sure this tag is present at the end of the configuration phase of the build lifecycle?

how does multi-project builds effect this?  each individual project of a multiproject build must have this tag as well.

**EDIT**

I was able to get back to this.  I got this to run and it executes the closure, problem is `project_hash` always null.  Now granted, I'm using testkit so i may be dealing with something weird in testkit.  see anything wrong?:

```
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
    this.project = project

    def metadata = new Metadata()

    // Create and install the extension object
    project.extensions.create('metadata', MetadataExtension, metadata)

    def ignore = project.tasks.create(METADATA_REPORT, MetadataReportTask)
    ignore.group = PLUGIN_GROUP
    ignore.description = 'Gets the detailed information for this project and formats it into a user readable report'

    project.afterEvaluate {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException(project.metadata.metadata.project_hash)
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't say if this is a java project? Android? C? something else?

Comment: Can you elaborate where/how `inventory_link: '124djsj39r'` is defined?

Comment: RaGe, it will be on java, javascript, android, c, c++, objective c, python, powerbuilder, scala, groovy, assembly and possibly cobol projects.

Comment: weston, it will be in the build.gradle file.  different value for each of the projects of many thousands of multiproject builds.

Answer (score 0):

Any code you put in the main body of your `build.gradle` script will run during the configuration phase. If you want it done last, just put it at the bottom.

```
if (inventory_link == null) //or whatever check makes sense
    throw new GradleException('Hey, you need to set the inventory_link')
```

Note that `clean` is not a "phase" in the [gradle build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) like init, config, execute. It is achieved via a task.

Comment: This is a distributed plugin, i can't put that in the build.gradle file because then all a developer has to do is delete it.  this is going to a distributed plugin and the CI server is going to be setup to detect if the plugin is installed or not.  If its not, its going to kick the build.  i just need to figure out how to execute a task at the end of the configuration phase of the lifecycle.

Comment: If you could do that, what's to stop them also doing that? I'm saying what is the end? If two tasks are set to run at "the end" which will run first? You should really only define dependencies. i.e. task A depends on task B.

Comment: Why is it so important that it happens at configuration stage? and not just hook into a task, or number of tasks?

Comment: the end is when the configuration phase stops and the build phase starts.  whats to stop a dev from doing the same thing?  the fact that we built into our sonar scanners the ability to find unauthorized plugins and dependencies.  i see that nexus gradle lint seems to do something very similar to this, once i can get back to this in a few hours i will give it a look and see if i can use that.

Comment: because step two of the verification is querying said inventory system to get the rest of the build information for the project.  Things like group, app name, etc are not being stored in the build file because they are managed outside of the source code

Comment: sorry, artifact name, not app name.  artifact names are not managed in the source, they are managed in our inventory system